# Fragment in minimize Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, fragment, onpause

I have a Timer in a fragment and I want the timer to pause when the app is minimize(user clicks home or recent apps).

What should I do?

It seems that the fragment doesnt have onPause! The parent activity has it, which is useless because there I don't have access to the timer.

I also tried to make home button and set on click listener for it but I got null pointer exception error and when I used the code below

```
     @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            if(item.getItemId()==android.R.id.home)
            {
                Log.d("IT home","clicked");
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
```

but it doesn't work. I didn't see anything it the Log cat.

Comment: fragment has ```onPause()``` method. I just looked at the docs

Comment: You're right thanks. I don't know why i couldn't use it in the first place

Comment: you're welcome. if this was helpful to you please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. also a vote up won't hurt :D

Answer (score 0):

according to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments) , fragments have an `onPause` method. you can use it normally like you would do in an activity.

read more about it in the documentation.

I hope this helps you.